# Parsing Command Line Arguments for Shell

Tags: c, argv, execv

I have this shell that I am writing for a summer project. I am trying to parse the command line for example,

If I call

```
ls -l
```

I need to parse the

```
-l
```

part.

So I can pass it in for the arguments vector that is used in side of `execv`. I know I am parsing it correctly but for some reason something is not with finding the directory. Am I perhaps missing something? Below is my code.

Comment: Aside from what I suggest in my answer, you'll also have to fix your declaration of `c`. At the point you declare `char *c[] = {full_cmd, argv, NULL};` neither `full_cmd` nor `argv` have been initialised, and garbage values will be copied into `c`. You need to initialise `c` *after* the values you need have been initialised.

Answer (score 5):

Although the `strtok` standard library function can be useful, you need to be aware of the shortcomings of its interface, which is basically a trap for the unwary.

In this program, you seem to have stumbled over both of the most common problems with the `strtok` interface. Please reread `man strtok` carefully in conjunction with this answer in order to avoid falling into these problems in the future. Also, do not use `strtok` as an example of good interface design. Instead, use it as a model for what to avoid:

#### Hidden global state

`strtok` operates on a string pointer which it keeps in a static variable. Whenever you call `strtok` with a non-NULL first argument, it first resets the value of this static variable to that string. At the end of each call to `strtok`, it sets its static variable to the address at which the next scan should start, which is just after the token it just found.

There is only one instance of the static variable in the whole program, so you can't interleave `strtok` scans on two different strings. Worse, you can't call a function which itself calls `strtok` inside a `strtok` scan of a string, because the call inside the function will reset the `strtok` state.

That means you have to be careful whenever you have more than one `strtok` scan in a program. In your case, after the initialization of the badly-named variable `env`:

```
token = strtok(env, ":");
```

you use `strtok` to divide your input command into pieces in the badly-named variable `argv`:

```
argv = strtok(buf_copy, " ");
```

so when you later want to find the next component of `env`:

```
token = strtok(NULL, ":");
```

`strtok`'s state no longer points into `env`; instead it points into `buf_copy` (and, with your particular input, at a point in `buf_copy` where no more tokens will be found).

#### Modification of an input argument

The first argument to `strtok` is a `char*`, not a `const char*`.

In general, if a library function has a string argument, the argument should be declared as `const char*` unless the function intends to modify the string. Or, to put it another way, a `const char*` declaration is a promise that no attempt will be made to modify the argument, and if the promise is not made, it's probably for a good reason.

And, indeed, if you read `strtok`'s documentation, you will see that it explicitly modifies its input string by overwriting some delimiter characters with a NUL character. This has the effect of permanently dividing the original string into separate tokens. Sometimes that's fine, but it can get you into a lot of trouble if you want to refer to the string's original value again in the future. Often you will find yourself making a copy of the original string in order to call `strtok` on it. (That's often a symptom of bad program design, or a signal that `strtok` wasn't really the right tool to use for parsing.)

In this particular program, the trap is that `getenv()` does not return a copy of the environment variable's value. It returns a pointer directly into the environment variable table. Although the return type of `getenv` is `char*`, which might lead you to believe that modifying the value is ok, the C standard clearly tells you not to:

> The string pointed to shall not be modified by the program

Unfortunately, this prohibition is not present in the Linux manpage for `getenv`, but that manpage does note that `getenv` gives you a pointer into the environment table. If you do modify the string returned by `getenv`, it is highly likely (though not guaranteed) that a subsequent call to `getenv` for the same environment variable will retrieve the modified value.

And that's precisely what you do: since you let `strtok` loose on the string returned by `getenv(PATH)`, a subsequent call to `getenv(PATH)` will see a value truncated at the first colon.